# Have to manually insert every number for a digital planner - Is there a way to automate this process?

Tags: software-recommendation, photoshop-scripting

I design dated planners on Etsy.

The most time-consuming part of creating the planners is that I have to manually retype the numbers for every date in each planner. I have three different types of dated spreads in each planner (yearly, monthly, weekly), so that's a total of 1,095 numbers I have to *manually* change every year. Over time I've found ways to slightly speed up the process, but it still takes a few hours straight of tedious work to do.

I'd really like to have the extra time cleared up for me so I can spend more time on the actual design rather than drilling through what seems like an automatable task.

P.S. To clarify, my current process is to open my template for each page type in Photoshop and retype each number in each individual text layer. I auto-select layers and click the checkmark when finished typing each number. Flatten. Save as PDF. Then undo the flattening and retype for the next set.

Comment: I think you're right that it can be scripted, but I also think it will be a fairly complex script. If possible with your design, you could generate the structure programmatically using HTML/CSS and convert to PDF with Python (or use Python drawing package) and then drop the PDFs in over the background you've designed.

Comment: Alternatively, use GIMP rather than PS. GIMP, being a piece of FOSS under the Unix philosophy, is extremely scriptable.